# Aweber Java Api

Tags: java, oauth, aweber

My goal is to create an aweber app that adds users to an email list I already have.

I currently have code that uses Oauth to get a token but this method also requires an aweber account users
to manually write their credentials in order to grant the app access. I would only ever be using my aweber 'app' 
for my own purposes and I want to automate the process of authentication. Look for the comment "//going to the url manually here".
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
package aweber.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest;
import org.scribe.model.Response;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
impo    rt org.scribe.model.Verb;
import org.scribe.model.Verifier;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

public class AweberStuffTest
{

    //To get your consumer key/secret, and view API docs, see https://labs.aweber.com/docs  
    private static final String ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_URL = "https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/";

    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "AkW******8QO0dMmmF";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "zfgmPsZkXBam6R***********YD";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(AWeberApi.class)
        .apiKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
        .apiSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
        .build();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("=== AWeber's OAuth Workflow ===");
        System.out.println();

        // Obtain the Request Token
        System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
        Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
        System.out.println("Got the Request Token!");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
        String foo = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
        System.out.println(foo);


        //going to the url manually here
        System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
        System.out.print(">>");
        Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println();

        // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
        System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
        Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
        System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
        System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
        System.out.println();

        // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
        System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_URL);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();
        System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(response.getBody());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thats it man! Go and build something awesome with AWeber and Scribe! :)");
    }

}
```

and

```
package aweber.test;

import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a;
import org.scribe.model.Token;

public class AWeberApi extends DefaultApi10a
{
  private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=%s";
  private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/request_token";
  private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/access_token";

  @Override
  public String getAccessTokenEndpoint()
  {
    return ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT;
  }

  @Override
  public String getRequestTokenEndpoint()
  {
    return REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT;
  }

  @Override
  public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token requestToken)
  {
    return String.format(AUTHORIZE_URL, requestToken.getToken());
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Seems like it would make more sense to have the api key associated with an account